# How do I plot two different observations on one plot using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, ggplot2

I created two data frames, DF and DF1.

```
date_time <- c("2018-06-25 10:11:11", "2018-06-25 17:30:30", "2018-06-26 
15:55:00", "2018-06-26 18:35:30", "2018-06-27 09:06:01", "2018-06-27 
20:15:30")

temperature <- c("15", "18", "16", "17", "14", "15")

DF <- data.frame(date_time, temperature)

date <- c("2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27")
average_temp_per_day <- c(“16.5”, ”16.5”, ”14.5”)

DF1 <-data.frame(date, average_temp_per_day)
```

I wanted to plot the columns within DF. So I used the following code.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Date_Time, temperature))+geom_point() + ggtitle('Temperature 
plot')
```

However I also want to plot the the average_temp_per_day observations, within DF1, into the graph I created above. How do I adapt my code in order to create this new graph?

Comment: `+ geom_point(data = DF1, aes(...))` You can just add another `geom_point` and specify the different data and variables within.

Comment: @LAP Thanks it works!

Comment: You are welcome!